# Pundit::NotAuthorizedError / Problem with pundit authorize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I'm trying to update user's adress in a form but i dont understant why i'm not authorize to perform, this is my code :

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @address = current_user.addresses.last
    authorize @address
    @address.update!(address_params)
  end

  private

  def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :city, :country, :postcode, :phone_number, :street_address, :optional_address, :user_id)
  end
end


class AddressPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end

    def update?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the error :

Pundit::NotAuthorizedError in AddressesController#update
not allowed to update? this Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the `update?` method within the nested `Scope` class, but it's supposed to be defined directly in the policy class.

Instead of this:

```
class AddressPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end

    def update?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

You need to do this:

```
class AddressPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end

  def update?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Your current code must be only calling `ApplicationPolicy#update?`, which must be returning `false`.

Comment: Take a look at [the Pundit README](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes), and you'll see how the `resolve` method is expected to be inside it, but these predicate methods are not.

Comment: Oh Tom Lord thank you i don't know how i have missed that error ahah :)

Comment: We've all been there :D